# Finding order of $85 \in \mathbb{Z}_{105}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

We can probably proceed as follows: $85n \equiv 0$ (mod $105$) $\iff 85n=105k$... But then what would be the next step? Diophantine equations or a similar idea?

Comment: If $85n=105k$ then $17n = 21k$. Since $(17,21) = 1$, the smallest $n$ satisfying this equation is exactly $n=21$.

Comment: $85=5\cdot 17$, $105=3\cdot 5\cdot 7$, and you're looking for the smallest multiple of $85$ that's a multiple of $105$, so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue from $$85n\equiv 0\pmod {105}\implies -20n\equiv 0\pmod {105}\implies 20n\equiv 0\pmod {105}$$

$$\implies 100n\equiv 0\pmod{105}\implies -5n\equiv 0\pmod{105}\implies 5n\equiv0\pmod{105}$$

Therefore, $5n=105k\implies n=21k$. Hence, the smallest $n$ is $21$. Indeed, $85\times 21\equiv 0\pmod{105}$.